# Insert previous day data from Table 1 to table 2 at 00:00:01 time

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have 2 tables in BigQuery. I have to insert the data from Table 1 to Table 2 but the data that I need to insert i in batch. It will insert the data at **00:00:01** time and it will insert all the previous data only. The condition that I have to apply is on **uuid_ts** which is a timestamp column

Table - 1

| id(integer) | uuid_ts(timestamp) | anonymous_id(string) |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 2022-02-26 02:04:25.480301 UTC | a012 |
| 2 | 2022-02-26 04:09:39.496484 UTC | 00a3 |

Table -2

| id(integer) | uuid_ts(timestamp) | anonymous_id(string) | video_ratio(string) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
|  |  |  |  |
|  |  |  |  |

What will be the query in BigQuery

Comment: Does 00:00:01 time means that if uuid_ts = 00:00:01 in table 1, it will insert into table 2? For previous data, will it cover ALL previous data (including other days before current day) or just the previous day? Is "previous day" will depend on the actual current day (D-1)?  It will also help if you provide expected output for us to create query for this.

Comment: For example today is Thursday, so at time 00:00:01 day will become Friday. So what I want is that at 00:00:01(Friday), it will insert all the data of Thursday(it will be million/billion of records) from table 1 to table 2. I will get records in Table 1 on daily basis,so I need to insert the records from Table 1 to Table 2 automatically at 00:00:01 time but the data will be only of previous day(not the whole data) and for applying any condition/filter, the column is uuid_ts(timestamp). I need to write the query in BQ only but may be in future, I can schedule this job in DAG but not as of now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This query satisfies your requirement on inserting the records of previous day from `table1` to `table2`:

```
INSERT INTO `tbl2` (id, uuid_ts, anonymous_id)
SELECT id, uuid_ts, anonymous_id  FROM `tbl1` 
WHERE DATE(uuid_ts) = DATE(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()) - 1;
```

Table1:
[image]

`CURRENT_TIMESTAMP()` as of:
[image]

Table2:
[image]

For automating the script to run every 00:00:01 of the current day, the available tool for that is [SCHEDULE](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/docs/scheduling-queries) feature in your query editor:
[image]

However,time metrics in `SCHEDULE` is until minutes only, for this limitation, you can decide if you want it to run at 12:00 AM or 12:01 AM, see configuration below:
[image]
[image]